# BeautifulSoup - combine consecutive tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have to work with the messiest HTML where individual words are split into separate tags, like in the following example:

```
<b style="mso-bidi-font-weight:normal"><span style='font-size:14.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>I</span></b><b style="mso-bidi-font-weight:normal"><span style='font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>NTRODUCTION</span></b>
```

That's kind of hard to read, but basically the word "INTRODUCTION" is split into

```
<b><span>I</span></b>
```

and

```
<b><span>NTRODUCTION</span></b>
```

having the same inline properties for both span and b tags.

What's a good way to combine these? I figured I'd loop through to find consecutive b tags like this, but am stuck on how I'd go about merging the consecutive b tags.

```
for b in soup.findAll('b'):
    try:
       if b.next_sibling.name=='b':
       ## combine them here??
    except:
        pass
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Expected output is the following

```
<b style="mso-bidi-font-weight:normal"><span style='font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>INTRODUCTION</span></b>
```

Comment: If you just want the text content, just do `node.text` where node is the parent of what you've show us.

Comment: In that `if `- do you mean `b.nextSibling` since I don't see a `p` symbol in your code.

Comment: I need to essentially re-write the HTML to clean it up, not just get the text. It's part of a larger effort.

Comment: @DannyStaple yes, b. Just edited it, thanks for catching it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could check if the `b.previousSibling` is a `b` tag, then append the inner text from the current node into that. After doing this - you should be able to remove the current node from the tree with `b.decompose`.

Answer (score 4):

The solution below combines text from all the selected `<b>` tags into one `<b>` of your choice and decomposes the others.

If you only want to merge the text from consecutive tags follow [Danny's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/490188/danny-staple) approach.

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div id="wrapper">
  <b style="mso-bidi-font-weight:normal">
    <span style='font-size:14.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;line-height:107%;font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>I</span>
  </b>
  <b style="mso-bidi-font-weight:normal">
    <span style='font-family:"Times New Roman",serif;mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>NTRODUCTION</span>
  </b>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
container = soup.select_one('#wrapper')  # it contains b tags to combine
b_tags = container.find_all('b')

# combine all the text from b tags
text = ''.join(b.get_text(strip=True) for b in b_tags)

# here you choose a tag you want to preserve and update its text
b_main = b_tags[0]  # you can target it however you want, I just take the first one from the list
b_main.span.string = text  # replace the text

for tag in b_tags:
    if tag is not b_main:
        tag.decompose()

print(soup)
```

Any comments appreciated.

Comment: Instead of checking `if tag is not b_main:` every time, you could use `for tag in b_tags[1:]: tag.decompose()`.

Comment: Also, this would work only if the part you want to join has a parent with an `id`. Otherwise, it would join all the text from different parts of the HTML. So, the best approach here would be using `previous_sibling` or `next_sibling`.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar As for the first comment, yeah sure, but only in this specific case. I wanted the code to be more universal so it still works if you choose the tag you want to preserve in some other way than the index ;) As for the `id`, I don't think it's necessary since any wrapping div or anything that you can target would be enough.

Comment: `id` is usually unique. But, if you use a class, it will join text from all the different `<div>` tags that have the same class name. If multiple tags with same class / id don't exist, it won't be a problem.

Comment: A simple example would be `<div class="wrapper"><b>t1</b><b>t2</b></div><p>some other text</p><div class="wrapper"><b>x1</b><b>x2</b></div>`. Your program would return the text as `t1t2x1x2`, where as it should be `t1t2` and another `x1x2`. Didn't test it, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Actually, I tested it with this HTML: `<div class="wrapper"><b><span>t1</span><b><span>t2</span></b></b></div><p>some other text</p><div class="wrapper"><b><span>x1</span></b><b><span>x2</span></b></div>` and it is returning the wrong output as mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar I totally get it, you're right. I updated the answer, so you can choose a container with `<b>` tags. Is it okay now? You can target the container however you want.

Comment: Yup, now it works. If you select one container at a time, it won't cause any problems.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I have used for this problem is to insert one element inside the other, then `unwrap()` it, which will preserve all nested text and tags -- unlike approaches using the text contents of the elements.

For example:

```py
for b in soup.find_all('b'):
    prev = b.previous_sibling
    if prev and prev.name == 'b':  # Any conditions needed to decide to merge
        b.insert(0, prev)  # Move the previous element inside this one
        prev.unwrap()  # Unwrap <b><b>prev</b> b</b> into <b>prev b</b>
```

Note the use of `previous_sibling` instead of `next_sibling` so that we don't modify subsequent parts of the soup that we are about to iterate over.

Then we might want to repeat the process with `<span>` to achieve the final result. Perhaps also check `b['style'] == prev['style']` if that condition is desired for merging.

Answer (score 0):

The adjacent answer combines only `text` tags, without preserving nested tags, such as `<i>`.
The following code does this.

For example, for this html:

```html
<div>
    <p>A<i>b</i>cd1, <i>a</i><b><i>b</i></b><i>cd2</i> abcd3 <i>ab</i></p>
    <p>cd4 <i>a</i><i>bsd5</i> <i>ab<span>cd6</span></i></p>
</div>
```

the result will be:

```html
<div>
    <p>A<i>b</i>cd1, <i>a<b>b</b>cd2</i> abcd3 <i>ab</i></p>
    <p>cd4 <i>absd5 ab<span>cd6</span></i></p>
</div>
```

In the `ignoring_tags_names` variable, you can set which tags are considered nested and ignored when merging. Any other tags will break the merging chain.

In the `re_symbols_ignore` variable, you can set text characters between the same tags to be ignored when concatenating. Any other characters will break the merging chain.

You can also specify a check for the identity of tag attributes. But their order is not checked. `{class: ['a', 'b']}` and `{class: ['b', 'a']}` are considered different and tags are not combined.

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString


def find_and_combine_tags(soup, init_tag_name: str, init_tag_attrs: dict = None or {}):
    def combine_tags(tag, tags: list):
        # appending the tag chain to the first tag
        for t in tags:
            tag.append(t)

        # unwrapping them
        for t in tag.find_all(init_tag_name):
            if t.name == init_tag_name and t.attrs == init_tag_attrs:
                t.unwrap()

    def fill_next_siblings(tag, init_tag_name: str, ignoring_tags_names: list) -> list:
        next_siblings = []
        for t in tag.next_siblings:
            if isinstance(t, NavigableString) and not re_symbols_ignore.match(t):
                next_siblings.append(t)
            elif isinstance(t, NavigableString) and re_symbols_ignore.match(t):
                next_siblings.append(t)
            elif t.name in ignoring_tags_names and t.attrs == init_tag_attrs:  # also checking the tag attrs
                next_siblings.append(t)
            else:
                # filling `next_siblings` until another tag met
                break

        has_other_tag_met = False
        for t in next_siblings:
            if t.name == init_tag_name and t.attrs == init_tag_attrs:
                has_other_tag_met = True
                break

        # removing unwanted tags on the tail of `next_siblings`
        if has_other_tag_met:
            while True:
                last_tag = next_siblings[-1]
                if isinstance(last_tag, NavigableString):
                    next_siblings.pop()
                elif last_tag.name != init_tag_name and last_tag.attrs != init_tag_attrs:
                    next_siblings.pop()
                else:
                    break
            return next_siblings

    # Ignore nested tags names
    if init_tag_name in ['i', 'b', 'em']:
        ignoring_tags_names = ['i', 'b', 'em']
    elif init_tag_name in ['div']:
        # A block tags can have many nested tags
        ignoring_tags_names = ['div', 'p', 'span', 'a']
    else:
        ignoring_tags_names = []

    # Some symbols between same tags can add into them. Because they don't changing of font style.
    if init_tag_name == 'i':
        # Italic doesn't change the style of some characters (spaces, period, comma), so they can be combined
        re_symbols_ignore = re.compile(r'^[\s.,-]+$')
    elif init_tag_name == 'b':
        # Bold changes the style of all characters
        re_symbols_ignore = re.compile(r'^[\s]+$')
    elif init_tag_name == 'div':
        # Here should be careful with merging, because a html can have some `\n` between block tags (like `div`s)
        re_symbols_ignore = re.compile(r'^[\s]+$')
    else:
        re_symbols_ignore = None

    all_wanted_tags = soup.find_all(init_tag_name)
    if all_wanted_tags:
        tag_groups_to_combine = []
        tag = all_wanted_tags[0]
        last_tag = tag
        while True:
            tags_to_append = fill_next_siblings(tag, init_tag_name, ignoring_tags_names)
            if tags_to_append:
                tag_groups_to_combine.append((tag, tags_to_append))  # the first tag and tags to append

            # looking for a next tags group
            last_tag = tags_to_append[-1] if tags_to_append else tag
            for tag in all_wanted_tags:
                if tag.sourceline > last_tag.sourceline \
                        or (tag.sourceline == last_tag.sourceline and tag.sourcepos > last_tag.sourcepos):
                    break
            if last_tag.sourceline == all_wanted_tags[-1].sourceline and last_tag.sourcepos == last_tag.sourcepos:
                break
            last_tag = tag

        for first_tag, tags_to_append in tag_groups_to_combine:
            combine_tags(first_tag, tags_to_append)

    return soup
```