# Clean up repeated and nested HTML tags in Python

Tags: python

I want to convert HTML snippets like

`<strong>Hi</strong><strong> </strong><em><strong>Tim</strong></em>`

with any complexity or levels into

`<strong>Hi <em>Tim</em></strong>`.

The implementation should handle:

- All tags
- All attributes with any values (meaning that it distinguishes them correctly)
- Adjacent equal tags (merge them)
- Nested tags in any depth (reorder and merge them)
- Maybe even know that some tags can be merged if they are separated by a space (like `strong` and `em`, but not `u`)

I thought I would find something in the BeautifulSoup or lxml packages or even Python itself. lxml's [`clean_html`](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#cleaning-up-html) at first looked promising to me. But I couldn't find anything. I also searched for other packages (like https://github.com/matthiask/html-sanitizer/, http://countergram.github.io/pytidylib/) and questions (like [BeautifulSoup - combine consecutive tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026264/beautifulsoup-combine-consecutive-tags), [Clean Up HTML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073881/clean-up-html-in-python)).

Code samples or links to packages are appreciated!

Comment: [BeautifulSoup - combine consecutive tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026264/beautifulsoup-combine-consecutive-tags) looks like exactly what you want; in what way is that insufficient?

Comment: @Hamms I should have mentioned that there can be any tags. E.g. `<a>t1</a><b><c><a>t2</a></c><d class="x"><a><a>t3</a></a></d></b>`.