# Remove redundant class names in HTML using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to convert:

```
<span class = "foo">data-1</span>
<span class = "foo">data-2</span>
<span class = "foo">data-3</span>
```

to

```
<span class = "foo"> data-1 data-2 data-3 </span>
```

Using BeautifulSoup in Python. This HTML part exists in multiple areas of the page body, hence I want to minimize this part and scrap it. Actually the mid `span` was with `em` class hence originally separated.

Comment: Have you tried? Please show us your attempts so far.

Comment: This approach can be used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027296/9205630 but the issue is that, I have different blocks of it many times in the HTML body.

Comment: The approach you link to could be used to find all `span` tags and join them into a single tag? Seems like exactly your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026264/beautifulsoup-combine-consecutive-tags/50027296#50027296) to show how this could be used for your `span` tags:

```
span_tags = container.find_all('span')

# combine all the text from b tags
text = ''.join(span.get_text(strip=True) for span in span_tags)

# here you choose a tag you want to preserve and update its text
span_main = span_tags[0]  # you can target it however you want, I just take the first one from the list
span_main.span.string = text  # replace the text

for tag in span_tags:
    if tag is not span_main:
        tag.decompose()
```